# How do I check if Windows desktop is locked

Tags: windows-7, autoit

**Q:** In AutoIt, how do I check if Windows desktop is locked

#### What I have

Let's take this example AutoIt script. It pings an URL in an indefinite loop and reports the response time in a tray tip.

```
While 1
    $responsetime = Ping("www.google.com")
    TrayTip("", $responsetime, 1)
    sleep(5000)
Wend
```

#### Desired result

The new script should only ping if the desktop is *not* locked. But I haven't found a reliable way to check for this

```
While 1
    $isLocked = secretFunctionIdontKnow
    If $isLocked = false Then
       Local $responsetime = Ping("www.google.com")
       TrayTip("", $responsetime, 1)
    EndIf
    sleep(5000)
Wend
```

*Hint:* The function [`WinExist("A")`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinExists.htm) seems not reliable enough because a desktop without any open windows will report back 0 (=false) even when unlocked

Comment: You won't get a title from the Lock Screen with `WinGetTitle`... :-(

Comment: But the Lock Screen is from the class `TaskSwitcherWnd`. So you can just see if the result of `WinGetClassList` has this entry at its first position... It will also be true if you use `{Alt}+{Tab}` for program switching, but I think this is a fair tradeoff to not do the ping while switching programs as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my comments above, you can use the following `secretFunctionIdontKnow` ;-)

```
Func secretFunctionIdontKnow()
    $classes = StringSplit(WinGetClassList("[ACTIVE]"), @LF, 2)
    Return $classes[0] == "TaskSwitcherWnd"
EndFunc
```

Fortunately the program switcher hasn't got a return value of `TaskSwitcherWnd`, so this seems to work for me under Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64 Bit...

Don't miss the brackets in your function call ;-)

Comment: It might be a wink faster if you don't use `StringSplit` but `StringLeft($list, StringInStr($list, @LF) - 1)`... up to you.

Comment: +1 That function is working. (btw. whats even better is that `{Alt}+{Tab}` doesn't give a true for me^^)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I experienced as well... But when you move the capture-cursor from the **AutoIt Window Information Tool** above the program switcher that occurs with `{Alt}{Tab}`, you will get the class `TaskSwitcherWnd` as a result... Anyways, the `TaskSwitcherWnd` window doesn't seem to be the active one, but one without a class recognisable by **AutoIt** as the function `WinGetClassList("[ACTIVE]")` will return `""`. Thus makes my `secretFunctionIdontKnow` returning false... viola.